# Automatic botpress test on slack

Tags: php, bots, slack, chatbot, slack-api

I use botPress on slack, it works when I say 'hello' the bot answer me.

But when I send 'hello' with a php script with curl request, the bot does not answer me... I must use php script to do automated scenario test.

That is my script :

```
  function sendToslack($message)
{
$ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
$data = http_build_query([
    "token" => "xoxp-330664869540-330140411569-331169805861-ac37690bbd76dff05d14c1602a3e94b5",
    "parse" => 'full',
    "as_user" => 'true',
    "link_names" => '1',
    "channel" => "#recrutement", //"#mychannel",
    "text" => $message, //"Hello, Foo-Bar channel message.",

]);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
 }

 sendToslack('hello');
```

with the parameter "as_user" => 'true', slack must not recognize that it's a script. So I don't know why he don't want answer.

I already checked all slack settings

Comment: Actually, that is not how it works. Despite sending with `as_user = true` your message on Slack will still be marked as coming from a bot (your Slack app) and not from a real user. It will also have the `App` tag next to its name. That is probably the reason the other bot does not answer you.

Comment: Oh ok ! Do you have a solution ?

Comment: And I checked it haven’t the App tag next to his name , it’s my profile who is used. No difference With me